# Netlify not support wildcard subdomain

Tags: deployment, netlify

In Netlify I have tried and even upgraded the paid plan with their community forums reference. But later found that they are not supporting wildcard subdomain configuration.

For the basic level subdomain with one-click app setup, Netlify is good. Except for wildcard domain it's a best to configure your frontend apps.

Answer (score 0):

For the basic level subdomain with one click app setup Netlify is good. Except wildcard domain its a best to configure your frontend apps.